# Codeigniter active record query with concat as join parameter

Tags: codeigniter, join, activerecord, concatenation

I currently have 2 tables in which I need to get data from.

My users table looks like:
ID   | first_name   | last_name  |  username

My data table looks like:
ID |   filename  |   doctorname  |  viewed

What I need to do match the first name and last name from the users table to the doctor name in the data table and the return the "filename" and "viewed" rows from this.

I can't seem to get the query right for it though. I'm using the active record class with code igniter. Ive also tried to have a separate function that concats the first and last name and returns it but I can't seem to pass that variable to the join section of the query.

```
  $avail = '1';
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from("users a");
    $this->db->where("username",$username);
    $this->db->where('CONCAT(first_name, '.', last_name) AS doctorname', FALSE);


    $this->db->join('data b', "doctor name = b.doctorName", "left");

    $result = $this->db->get();
    // print_r($this->db->last_query());
    return $result->result();
```

Anyone know whats going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Please post your error... Also post the query by, adding the following before return :
echo $this->db->last_query(); exit;

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$avail = '1';
$this->db->select('a.*,b.filename,b.viewed');
$this->db->from("users as a");
$this->db->join('data as b', "CONCAT(a.first_name, '.', a.last_name) = b.doctorName", "left");
$this->db->where("a.username",$username);
$result = $this->db->get();
// print_r($this->db->last_query());
return $result->result();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @suyash ! For some reason its not returning the filename and the $doctorname variable in my view is throwing an "undefined property" error. Is there a way of putting a space in between the first_name and last_name when concatenating it? I think that might be whats throwing it as there is a space between them in the data table

Comment: concat will add a '.' like. If first_name is Suyash and last_name is Maurya, then concat will compare as Suyash.Maurya from another table. If you want to add space in the name then just leave a blank space like: CONCAT(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name) instead of '.'.